# Is this prepositional phrase acting as an adjective?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, prepositional-phrases

**The example**

*Create a referral to a specialist.*

**The question**

Is that sentence grammatically correct?

I think it is because the prepositional phrase is acting as an adjective (modifying "referral") rather than an adverb (modifying "create"). If it were intended to modify "create" as an adverb then I don't think "to" works.

Comment: It seems OK to me. But the PP _to a specialist_ is a complement of "referral", not a modifier. Even if it was a modifier, I would avoid describing it as an adjective; it's not - it's a PP.

Comment: _a referral to a specialist_ is the event NP version of the VP _refer (s.o.) to a specialist_, and takes the same preposition. Prepositional phrases can modify practically anything, which is to say they can "act as" adverbs, adjectives, nouns, or conjunctions.  As @BillJ says, it's quite grammatical.

Comment: You are correct; an adverbial interpretation of *Create to a specialist a referral / Create a referral to a specialist* doesn't work. But *Create for a specialist a referral / Create a referral for a specialist* does (it changes the meaning though).

Comment: @BillJ - Thanks for the reply.  PP's can be adjectives, though. Are you suggesting they can't be? I got it from this resource: https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-7/prepositions/lesson-8/adjective-or-adverb-prepositional-phrases

When I search "complement", I only get results stating that the complement is what follows the preposition in a prepositional phrase, which clearly isn't the case here. Do you happen to have a resource or any tips on finding a resource?  This is work-related and I need to back up what I am saying to coworkers.

Comment: You're confusing word class (part of speech) and function. PPs can be modifiers or complements. Adjective is a word class (POS) not a function; they can function as modifiers or complements, just as PPs can.

Comment: Matthews in _The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Linguistics_ defines 'complement' as 'A syntactic element seen as completing the construction of another element’ (BillJ - the syntactic concept construction is preferable to the semantic concept meaning). He goes on to say, more specifically, that it applies to elements other than the subject which are within the valency of a verb or other lexical unit.

Comment: Whether or not one sees 'to a specialist' as modifying or being a complement to 'referral', it's certainly identifying _the type of referral_. But it's not just adjectives that do this.

Comment: Although the sentence is grammatically OK, it should be noted that it seems to belong to some bureaucratic jargon. In ordinary English, one would just use the verb *refer*, rather than the phase *create a referral*.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct; "to a specialist" is a complement of  "referral" (in the terminology of Huddleston & Pullum (2002)). Note that you can use "a referral to a specialist" as a noun phrase in a variety of contexts, e.g. "A referral to a specialist was necessary" or "She needed a referral to a specialist." But you can't use "create" in isolation in this way; "A referral was what she created to a specialist" is obviously wrong.

Comment: According to BillJ and the esteemed authors of CGEL, 'But the PP _to a specialist_ is a complement of "referral", not a modifier'. There are different terminologies in play here, and it is courteous on ELU and scholarly to add a supporting reference when asserting one of several different analyses.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My mistake; I've updated my answer to use the term "complement."

Comment: I wasn't saying their stance is inviolate, rather that it needs to be pointed out where distinct analyses come from.

Comment: The wording of this post makes it sound like there is some other analysis of "to a specialist" here. What is it?

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Wait, re: our earlier conversation: did you search my post history for the phrase "in the terminology of Huddleston & Pullum (2002)" so that you could find one to be angry at?

Comment: @alphabet I did search the history for that phrase, yes, to see how you'd been using it because you drew my attention to it. However, I left my comment here because the phrase makes it sound as if there's another analysis available. Why do you say "to be angry at"?

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Anyway, in this case I don't know if there exist other common analyses, which is precisely why I qualified my answer with "in the terminology..." If you happen to know that such analyses do not exist in this case and that H&P's analysis is the only acceptable one, I can update my answer.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Anyway, if you have recommendations of other sources that I should read to confirm that this analysis is the only common one, I'm open to them. But I still need to finish CGEL first.

Answer (score 0):

- It seems OK to me. But the PP [preposition phrase] *to a specialist* is a complement of "referral", not a modifier. Even if it was a modifier, I would avoid describing it as an adjective; it's not - it's a PP.                                                                                     – BillJ

................

- *a referral to a specialist* is the event NP version of the VP *refer (someone) to a specialist*, and takes the same preposition. Prepositional phrases can modify practically anything, which is to say they can "act as" adverbs, adjectives, nouns, or conjunctions. As @BillJ says, it's quite grammatical.                                                                                             – John Lawler